# android sqlite timestamp column

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an Android SQLite table that has 5 columns in it. One of them is a timestamp.
How can I check the timestamp **(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)** for all of them and compare it to the local time on the Android then decide which row to read?

Comment: Do you want to compare Timestamp value with the current date?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the sql date functions : http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

And you can obtain your local datetime with "new Date()" in Java.

In my application, I usually store unix timestamp and I can do operations I need quite easily with "new Date().getTimeinMillis()". It's simpler and more performant.